# Number of ways to transform binary sequences into another one using given operations

Tags: combinatorics, binary, combinatorics-on-words

You're allowed to perform one of four operations each time on a binary sequence:

1. Delete the rightmost `0` in the sequence (if it exists)
2. Turn the rightmost `0` into `1` (if it exists)
3. Insert `0` to a position such that it becomes the rightmost `0` of the new sequence
4. Turn a `1` into `0` (if it exists) such that it becomes the rightmost `0` of the new sequence

Operation 3&4 are basically inversions of operation 1&2 respectively.

For example, you can turn `1` into `111` with the following process using 8 operations: $1\xrightarrow{3}01\xrightarrow{2}11\xrightarrow{3}101\xrightarrow{4}100\xrightarrow{1}10\xrightarrow{2}11\xrightarrow{3}110\xrightarrow{2}111$.

Now the problem is to find the number of ways to transform $\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{n\text{ ones}}$ into $\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{m\text{ ones}}$ ($n\le m$) using **exactly $2k$ operations**. Two ways are considered different if and only if there exists a time where two sequences differ.

The solution to this problem turns out to be

$$
(2k-1)!!\sum_{i=0}^{\min\{n,m\}}\binom k{m-i}\binom mi\binom{k+m-i}{n-i}
$$

I've proved this for the case $k=m-n$, but currently I can't find a complete proof. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The first step (1 -> 01) does not comply with operation 3.

Comment: By "it becomes the rightmost `0` of the new sequence" I mean it becomes the rightmost one among all the `0`s in the new sequence.

Comment: @m-wind Why do you say that?

Comment: Where does the solution $(2k-1)!!\sum_{i=0}^{\min\{n,m\}}\binom k{m-i}\binom mi\binom{k+m-i}{n-i}$ come from? (and how do you know that it's correct?)

Comment: The author of this problem gave out this solution but now I can't get in touch with him. I've proved its correctness for $k=m-n$ and wrote a program to enumerate all the valid cases, which turns out that the solution is correct for $n,m,t<=6$.